# How to present the same modalView after dismissing it once

Tags: cocoa-touch, modalviewcontroller

I'm having some problem trying to present a modal view controller after it has been presented the first time, so I just start a little test method, it presents, dismisses and presents again the same controller modally.

```
// This is just test Code.
MYViewController *vc = [[MYViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self  presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

I get the error:

```
2011-11-15 09:50:42.678 Proyecto3[1260:11603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <RootViewController: 0x6d9d090>.'
```

The documentation does not add any clue here.

Answer (score 1):

@David, make the `MYViewController` an instance variable, and initialize it like this:

```
if (myInstance==nil)
     //create instance of MYViewController
     //myInstance.delegate=self
//present modal VC
```

In `MYViewController` create a protocol to co-ordinate dismissing `MYViewController` may be on a `done` or `cancel` button. In the button action call some thing like

```
    done 
    {
       if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(willDismissModalView)])
       {
           [delegate willDismissModalView];
       }
   }
```

and in `willDismissModalView` method of your VC dismiss `MYViewController`. This way you can do it 'n' times.

Comment: That's how I do it in my app (this is just test code). See my unanswered post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076211/what-can-make-presentmodalviewcontroller-not-ending-in-viewwillappear-being-call

Answer (score 0):

In your code [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 will do nothing to the modalViewController,since here the "self" is the viewController from where you are trying to present a modalViewController "vc".Again you are presenting a modalViewController which is already presented.this will result in a termination.

**You can dismiss the modalViewController vc in that viewController,here vc.**

Comment: But that's the opposite the docs say: "dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:
Dismisses the modal view controller that was presented by the receiver.". Also in the View Controller Programming Guide, a modal view controller is dismissed this way from the parent controller.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot present/dismiss the view controller while it is animated, I think this works

```
MYViewController *vc = [[MYViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:NO];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self  presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

But I don't really see any reason for doing it, why would you want to dismiss and re-present a modal view controller which is already presented?

Comment: This is a test code to see what's wrong in my app. I'm trying to present a modalViewController a second time after dismissing it and it never shows again. See my unanswered post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076211/what-can-make-presentmodalviewcontroller-not-ending-in-viewwillappear-being-call